# Issue with a clientApplicationContext xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, spring

I'm running a tutorial I got off the web and I'm getting an error:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'orderService' defined in 
    class path resource [clientApplicationContext.xml]: 
    Invocation of init method failed;  
    nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: 
    Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL.
```

It failed with:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL.
```

It's for Spring 2.5, Tomcat 7, Eclipse Helios and java 1.6.

All I did was change this value from port 9090 to 8080:

```xml
<property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" 
          value="http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL"/>
```

I have the file in two places: under java resources and also under src. I used the defaults for the app code as I just pulled it into my project and the port number is the only thing I changed, other than creating a new dynamic web project in eclipse.

In the main method here is the offending code:

```java
ApplicationContext ctx = 
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clientApplicationContext.xml");
```

There is an applicationContext.xml file under web-inf that I added my bean definition to:

```xml
<bean id="orderService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean" >
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.javacoda.jaxws.order.client.OrderService"/>
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="com.javacoda.jaxws.order"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="DefaultOrderServiceService"/>
    <property name="portName" value="DefaultOrderServicePort"/>
</bean>
```

Looks right, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If I get it, the right xml is called (otherwise it would fail complaining about port 9090). My next question would be: is there actually a WSDL at this address?

Comment: When I run this url: http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL with the server running I get a 404 error, so something isn't setup right. On another tutorial I had to publish the wsdl first and when I pointed to the url the wsdl came up.  File not found is the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you that it:

```
Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL
```

Can you access this WSDL from the browser?

Look at the setter of the WSDL:

```
/**
 * Set the URL of the WSDL document that describes the service.
 */
public void setWsdlDocumentUrl(URL wsdlDocumentUrl) {
    this.wsdlDocumentUrl = wsdlDocumentUrl;
}
```

There is no magic here => it expects a WSDL to be at that location.

You can publish WSDL dynamically:

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="holiday"                                                           
    portTypeName="HumanResource"                                                         
    locationUri="/holidayService/"                                                       
    targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions">                               
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/hr.xsd"/>                                                  
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

or statically:

```
<sws:static-wsdl id="orders" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/orders.wsdl"/>
```

Read more about "[Publishing the WSDL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-publishing-wsdl)" and "[Automatic WSDL exposure](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure)"

Comment: No, when I have tomcat up it's not finding the wsdl.

Comment: so how do you export that WSDL to be at "http://localhost:8080/services/order?WSDL" in the first place?

Comment: I'm not doing that.  So I have to do a publish of some kind for that?  This is basic stuff, but I'm just now setting up jax-ws from scratch.  I've done 2 tutorials and they had a publish class that created the wsdl.  So what is the proper way to export the wsdl?  Sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: there are no newbie questions, no human has an ultimate knowledge. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Well, I'm eating humble pie anyway.  I just want to get this thing working. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use class path prefix that should solve the problem, If you use class path prefix java run time will find the context file under src/main/resources

```
   ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:clientApplicationContext.xml")
```